# Is it possible to change the logger without building ROS packages (ROS2)

Tags: ros, ros2, logger

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to change the logger, spdlog to log4cxx, without having to rebuild individual ros packages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/366350/is-it-possible-to-change-the-logger-without-building-ros-packages-(ros2)/) by [MHx](https://answers.ros.org/users/61446/mhx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2020-11-25

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately you'll need to rebuild `rcl`. [rcl picks the logger to use at compile time](https://github.com/ros2/rcl/blob/2ee91d8e4c02ce04899c792c1b28119673b5bf61/rcl/CMakeLists.txt#L18), which [by default is `rcl_logging_spdlog`](https://github.com/ros2/rcl/blob/2ee91d8e4c02ce04899c792c1b28119673b5bf61/rcl/cmake/get_default_rcl_logging_implementation.cmake#L33).

Add `rcl_logging_log4cxx` and `rcl` to your workspace, then choose the logging implementation by setting the environment variable `RCL_LOGGING_IMPLEMENTATION`.

```
export RCL_LOGGING_IMPLEMENTATION=rcl_logging_log4cxx
colcon build --cmake-clean-cache --packages-select rcl_logging_log4cxx rcl
```

There may be more relevant info in this thread: https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros2-logging/6469/24

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2020-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2